# What can I do if someone is being rude to me when I ask a question just because I am a beginer?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I faced this problem a lot when I was new to Stackoverflow. I accept that my questions were not up to the mark, but I tried my best to search answers for them before posting. What should someone facing a similar problem do?

**EDIT 1**

true i can flag that person. how do we stop them in a long run?

Comment: Rudeness is not tolerated. You can flag such comments as "rude or offensive".

Comment: Do you have an example of such a comment?

Comment: I've looked through all your questions and the associated comments; I haven found anything resembling rudeness. Could you include a specific anonymous example of a comment that was made that you consider rude?

Comment: Why do you think this has to do with being a beginner? Don't you think it may have more to do with the quality of postings?

Comment: Quite a few serial upvoting reversed events I see there in your profile too. Are you trying to game the site?

Answer (score 26):

> In th above code due to some syntax error (most probably in echo) **i am getting awkward result and the HTML codes are also not working nothing in the HTML part is running , result is just WHite screen with Hello(in bold)**

I did not have to look very far to find this phrase in one of your questions, it elicited a snippy remark from another SO user.  This is the usual way that "rude" comments are born, a response to behavior considered rude.  Some basic tips:

- Use a spell-checker to eliminate simple typos
- Use bold text carefully, it is considered "shouting" in the Western world.  You especially do not want to bold the weakest part of your question
- When somebody posts a snippy remark, do not retaliate with a snippy remark back.  That just starts an endless cycle that helps nobody
- About anybody knows that "i am getting awkward result" is quite a useless diagnostic.  You are expected to spend the time to flesh that out to *something* that indicates failure.  If you have no idea how to do that then ask a question about *that* instead
- You are cheating on your rep, asking friends or using a sock puppet account to vote on your posts.  You already know that doesn't work, those fakes votes have been rolled-back before, looks like you found a way to cheat the machine.  This kind of fraud is considered *very* rude in the Western world.  Don't do it, reputation is not just a number
- Change your SO user name, you are no Einstein yet.

Be sure to be respectful of the time and sensibilities of other SO users that can help you and show evidence for that.  They'll gladly return the favor and you don't have to look at snippy remarks anymore.  And stop cheating, it is important that you do, you'll only cheat yourself.

Comment: "Use bold text carefully" may need to be be "**Use bold text carefully!**". Possibly, OP needs to enhance the brightness of his monitor.

Answer (score 6):

If they're *berating* you in comments, flag it as "rude or offensive".  Then don't call any more attention to it.  Don't engage in any petty squabbles over what's rude or not; if they're truly being a jerk, flag their comment and let a moderator deal with it.

If they're making comments about the quality of the question, then take some more time to add a bit of polish to it.  If you've done what you can, then clarify it based on the guidance of constructive comments.